# Opensource WAN replication in Hazelcast 3.6

Tags: hazelcast

Is WAN Replication still supported in 3.6 opensource version?

`com.hazelcast.wan.impl.WanNoDelayReplication` is no longer there and the WAN pages differ quite a bit:

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/wan.html
http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html/wan.html

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Hazelcast 3.6, out of the box WAN replication implementations are enterprise only, those are;

- `com.hazelcast.enterprise.wan.replication.WanNoDelayReplication`
- `com.hazelcast.enterprise.wan.replication.WanBatchReplication`

But if you'd like to use WAN replication in open source, you may create your own WAN replication implementation by implementing `com.hazelcast.wan.WanReplicationEndpoint` interface and register it same as before.

Also, multi-html version of documentation is not supported anymore so the link that you've provided for 3.6 is not valid. Below is the new link;

http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#wan

Comment: That's unfortunate. It's not feasible to maintain own implementation of `com.hazelcast.wan.WanReplicationEndpoint`. So we either stay with 3.5.x or implement replication at higher level. Hmmm...

Comment: As always it's money / time trade-off. if it's not feasible to maintain your own implementation of WAN replication we will more than happy to have your company among our customers.